# Show datalabels value true when export charts in any format using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to show datalabels value using a standard format when export charts to any format in highcharts. I am providing a demo for a detailed explanation.

Comment: This is a demo for reference http://jsfiddle.net/upendrasharma221/ham570tm/

Comment: in simple way change datalabels format when exporting menu items are clicked.

Comment: Check [this bug report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1562). Note `chart.options.chart.forExport` flag is the key one - use one formatter, when you will check if chart is for exporting or default one.

Comment: @PawełFus Yes this is the perfact solution but when we drill down charts and export them, it is showing same value twice, how to remove that

Comment: This is the url for demo http://jsfiddle.net/upendrasharma221/ham570tm/
when you drilldown and then export the chart datalabels is shown twice in the png.

Comment: Your demo doesn't have drilldown?

Comment: @PawełFus This is the demo just click on slice named One and then download drilldown chart http://jsfiddle.net/upendrasharma221/ham570tm/2/

Comment: Oh, that issue. See [this ticket](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3649) - it's bug in PhantomJS 1.x, fixed in PhantomJS 2.x. Try out workarounds posted there.

Comment: I tried some of the solutions given in this ticket, but no effect. After that i searched about this more and found that it can be done simply by 
plotOptions: {
        dataLabels: {
                style: {
                        textShadow: 0
                }
        }
}